# mockito testing verify with 0 calls

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

```
    Class MyClass{
    method3(){
      if(condition){
        method1()
      }

      else{

      method2()

      }

    }

     method1(){
     //do woo
      }

     method3(){
        //do foo
      }
 }
```

I am trying to test `method3` only if case  is called so else method is not called.

```
   MyClass myClassMock=   mock(MyClass.class);
         myClassMock.method3();
         verify( myClassMock, times(0)).method2();
```

But then this calls my `method2`  and throws null pointer inside `method2`. How can I test this  without calling `method2` because my behavior wont call `method2`.

Comment: Once I fixed the compilation problems this test snippet worked just fine for me. Could you include a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care what was returned from `method2` you can mock the method as well:

```
when(mock.method2(anyString())).thenAnswer("anything");
```

You can replace `anyString` and use the following:

```
when(mock.method2(any(MyClass.class))).thenReturn(anInstanceOfMyClass);
```

or

```
verify(mock, never()).method2();
```

or

```
when(mock.method2()).thenReturn(instanceOfProperClass);
```

Comment: But then this calls method2() .I dont want method 2 be called.inside method 2 I am calling 3 rd party interfaces and call goes there and fails with null pointer.

Comment: Does it take any parameters? Use one of two first approaches.

Comment: Thanks will try it