# How can I test Json.parser is not called with mockito java?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, playframework, mocking, mockito

I want to verify Json.parse is never called in a function using unit test but i'm not using mockito correctly. would appreciate some help.

tried -

1. `when(Json.parse(wsResponse.getBody())).thenThrow(new Exception("error msg"))`

but got an error -
`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException` although method signature includes throws Exception.

2. tried to use verify and never but verify waits for a function

something like this -

`verify(Json.parse(wsResponse.getBody()),never());`

but got an error -  `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException:  Argument passed to verify() is of type ObjectNode and is not a mock!`

src I looked at -

> https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-exceptions **
> [How can I test that a function has not been called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282390/how-can-i-test-that-a-function-has-not-been-called) **
> [How to verify that a specific method was not called using Mockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862659/how-to-verify-that-a-specific-method-was-not-called-using-mockito) **
> [mockito testing verify with 0 calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772389/mockito-testing-verify-with-0-calls)

Answer (score 1):

The Json.parse method is a static method. In order to mock it and test you will need powermockito. So please add those dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

After adding those you can run tests with powermockito by including those lines:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(fullyQualifiedNames = "com.test.*")
```

Then if you want to mock a static method you do it like this:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Json.class);
```

Then you need to call the method under test:

```
underTest.testMethod();
```

In the end you need to tell powermockito that we want this method to be never called:

```
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.never());
Json.parse(Mockito.any());
```

Comment: thank you @Guts ! this one really helped me, I found another approach which worked for me but your way is definitely more general. (upvoted but i guess i'm too new)

Answer (score 0):

@Guts answer is more general but requires PowerMockito (another lib), it is still good in my opinion.

This one also worked for me -
I mock the wsResponse and checked if the returned body is not a type of json or csv. it gives me the same result (in my specific case), although it is not as general.

`when(wsResponse.getBody()) .thenReturn("{}") .thenReturn("Version Id,Version Name");`